# "Something went wrong. Please contact support" when using Send to Salesforce action in Sales Cloud for Slack

Tags: slack-salesforce-app

When using the message context menu in Slack

[image]

Result is error `Something went wrong. Please contact support`

- We've installed Sales Cloud for Slack app in Slack
- SFDC user has Sales Cloud for Slack user permission
- Account and Opportunity records both have `Add Link to Slack` button
- User has granted permission for `Sales Cloud for Slack` to access Salesforce
- SFDC user can successfully create channels in Slack from SFDC
- User from within Slack can search SFDC, create records, etc using the `Sales Cloud for Slack` app

But the Slack context menu on a message `Send to Salesforce Sales Cloud for Slack` as shown in the image above fails and requests me to contact Support.  *Not good*.

Answer (score 2):

*Well, I did contact Support*.

As far as I can tell, the `Send to Salesforce (Sales Cloud for Slack)` context action is undocumented (or at least I couldn't find it (unlike the one for the [Send to Salesforce Service Cloud for Slack](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.slack_push_message.htm&type=5))

Turns out that if you **don't have chatter enabled** on Account or Opportunity, you'll get the error `Something went wrong. Please contact support`.

- Our org doesn't use Chatter so to support the Slack context action, I had to enable Chatter (`Setup > Feed Tracking`) on Account and Opportunity.
- This gets past the error